# Custom border css and background image

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a custom border in css by using the *border-image* tag.
The background colour i'm using is the same colour as the border. But it doesn't fill the whole height.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

 div{
 border:15px solid transparent;
 width:250px;
 }

 div p {
 background-color: #74c7a9;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 }


 #round {
 -webkit-border-image:url(border2.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 5 */
 -o-border-image:url(border2.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
 border-image:url(border2.png) 30 30 round;
 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>


 <div id="round">
  <p>Here, the image is tiled (repeated) to fill the area. 
  </p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably ask in the form of a question (I'm guessing that's why this got downvoted), but I think you're looking for the CSS attribute `box-sizing: border-box`.

MDN article on box-sizing here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

The space that you see between the p background and the div border is the margin (top and bottom) of the p.

You can set it off with

```
p {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

if you feel that this way it gets too small, add

```
p {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

or, otherwise (may be easier) set the background in the div and not in the p